# Call a function from within same function in Javascript with global variables

Tags: javascript, function

I am making a XML-driven homepage. A menu structure is generated and when clicking on an menu element the content on the page is changed. When clicking on a level x element, its child is presented in a list in the main div. This is done by a function, changePage(id), that takes an id as argument to find correct XML-node to get the information.

I want this list elements to be links and when clicked on they should call changePage-function. This is used to step down in the tree.

```
var root = loadXML(aXML.xml);

function changePage(id){
var current_node = root;  // <-- here I get error when clicking on the a-element.
... // creating list
var aElement = document.createElement('a');
aElement.onclick = new Function("changePage('" + index + "')");
}
```

When I click on my menu item everything works but when I click on the generated list-element I get an error that "current_node is not defined". It seemse that root-variable cant be found when clicking on child.

What is wrong and what can i do to solve this?

Comment: You should use [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) instead of `new Function`, e.g. `aElement.onclick = function(event) {changePage(index)};`. That said, I don't think that the problem is in the code you show here.

Comment: I changed to closures. Looked better. I found my problem also, I wrote wrong id so my function couldn't find current_node because it crashed before that.

Comment: http://jquery.com/ might be worth a look

Comment: hi there, seems like you're approaching this in quite a flash centric way, any chance you can post the full code, it's probably a variable scope thing. ALso you know there's no 'root' in js right

Comment: So you want to create a recursion function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi from what you have there you are killing the browser with new Functions ( overwriteing the old one )

Instead of:

```
 aElement.onclick = new Function("changePage('" + index + "')");
```

you could use:

```
 aElement.onclick = arguments.callee(index);
```

"arguments" is a keyword in js and contains an object with all the parameters passed to the function ( i.e. arguments[0] ) and also contains "callee" (the function itself) and "caller" (the function from which is called ). The second one (caller) is not cross-browser.

Best regards,